# Dividing the alphabet into parties for elections - C language

Tags: c, loops, alphabetical

I want to write a program that takes an input from the user of "leading camps", and divides 26 letters in alphabet into 3 parties. for example if I choose the leading camps to be A-E-H, the three parties will be: 1) A,B,C,D 2) E,F,G 3) H-Z, and they the next input will be the votes (which are announced online), for example, if I enter the series of votes "fDFFGCcdC", the leading party will be the one that includes letters A-D, because it got 5 votes, and the others took 4 and zero, and so on.

Here is what I wrote so far:

Notes: Lead* are the leading camps.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{

    char Lead_1,Lead_2,Lead_3, vote;
    int counter_1=0,counter_2=0,counter_3=0;

    printf("Please enter the camps leaders:");
    scanf("%c%c%c", &Lead_1,&Lead_2,&Lead_3);

    printf("please enter the votes:");

    scanf(" %c", &vote);
    while(vote != '!')
    {
        scanf("%c", &vote);

        if((vote >= Lead_1) && (vote < Lead_2) || (vote >= (Lead_1 + 32) && vote < (Lead_2 +32)))
            counter_1++;

        if((vote >= Lead_2) && (vote < Lead_3) || (vote >= (Lead_2 + 32) && vote < (Lead_3 +32)))
            counter_2++;

        if((vote >= Lead_3) || (vote >= (Lead_3 + 32)))
            counter_3++;


        if (counter_1 > counter_2 && counter_1 > counter_3)
            printf("%c", Lead_1);
        else if (counter_2 > counter_1 && counter_2 > counter_3)
            printf("%c", Lead_2);
        else if (counter_3 > counter_1 && counter_3 > counter_2)
            printf("%c", Lead_3);
        else
        {
            if((vote >= Lead_1) && (vote < Lead_2) || (vote >= (Lead_1 + 32) && vote < (Lead_2 + 32)))
                printf("%c", vote);
            if((vote >= Lead_2) && (vote < Lead_3) || (vote >= (Lead_2 + 32) && vote < (Lead_3 + 32)))
                printf("%c", vote);
            if((vote >= Lead_3) || (vote >= (Lead_3 + 32)))
                printf("%c", vote);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I'm having a problem with the output. for example if I enter the leading camps AEH, and enter the votes bAzz! the output is AzHH instead of AAAH.

Comment: CAN someone tell me why people are down voting?  what did I do wrong ??

Comment: @BillLynch I said to look at the change history. I'm sorry if was because of system problems.

Comment: No description about the required output.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that based on the votes "fDFFGCcdC", we have to come up with parties A-E-H. Besides, A is the leading party , E is the second leading party & H is the third party {based on number of votes they got}.

If my understanding is right, you can follow this:

Create a hash table for 26 letters and initialize it.

```
hash[26] = {0}
```

get the count of characters in votes.

```
hash[vote[i] - 'a'] ++
```

Now you got the array of count of votes. {which has max, second max, min}

Based on maximum, second maximum and minimum values, set the ranges and parties.

Comment: Im not sure that I learnt such thing, but I wrote a code now and it seems like it has an error, I would like if u take a look

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void){
    char party[4][2];
    int votes[3] = {0};
    int i;
    char ch;
    *party[3] = 'Z' + 1;//sentinel
    //input format [alphabet for party1]-[alphabet for party2]-[[alphabet for party3]
    puts("input devide party :");
    if(3==scanf("%1[A-Z]-%1[A-Z]-%1[A-Z]", party[0], party[1], party[2])
       && *party[0] < *party[1] && *party[1] < *party[2] && *party[2] < *party[3]){
        for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
            printf("party%d : ", i + 1);
            for(ch = *party[i]; ch < *party[i+1]; ++ch){
                if(ch != *party[i])
                    putchar(',');
                putchar(ch);
            }
            puts("");
        }
        puts("input votes :");
        ch = '_';
        while(scanf(" %c", &ch) && ch != '!'){
            if(isalpha(ch)){
                ch = toupper(ch);
                if(ch < *party[1])
                    ++votes[0];
                else if(ch < *party[2])
                    ++votes[1];
                else if(ch < *party[3])
                    ++votes[2];
            }
        }
        for(i = 0; i < 3; ++i){
            printf("vote of party%d : %d\n", i+1, votes[i]);
        }
    } else {
        puts("invalid input!");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the effort, I want some time to figure out this code. Btw, I wrote I code of my own, and I got  an infinite loop, can u see my mistake?

Comment: @F1sargyan In your code there are many problems. Cause an infinite loop is a condition of while-loop (`counter_1!=counter_2 || counter_1!=counter_3 || counter_2!=counter_3`) is bad. The value does not change. also this does not need to  loop .

Comment: I edited it. the last lines are in case both counts were equal, so the leader will be the last one to get the vote, but I still don't get an output for some reason

Comment: but I want to compare between letters and not numbers, and its defined as char, it should be between ' ' right ?

Comment: @F1sargyan but `vote` is one character. also `Lead_1` is one charater of A-Z from user input. Be enclosed in `' '` should not be enclosed the variable name, it means the literal.

Comment: I tried without the '' it ddn't work. the output was numbers, i want the output to be letters. for example : the leading parties AAAH

Comment: @F1sargyan  _the output was numbers_ Because `printf("%d", Lead_1);`. should be `printf("%c", Lead_1);`

Comment: ok I think im getting somewhere now. except that there is a problem with the output. for example if I enter the leading camps AEH, and enter the votes bAzz! the output is AzHH instead of AAAH.

Comment: @F1sargyan Why `AAAH` is the correct output? BTW  I think that the result should  be outside the loop.